# Laravel - how to construct a date for the query to return results since beginning

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am doing queries in Laravel 5.2 based on what timespan user selects and one of the options is since beginning, for number of views, comments and so on. I am sending `from` and `to` dates with ajax.
I wonder what kind of date format should I sent in order to get all the rows from DB?

In this line I am creating range of dates for selected period:

```
$period = new DatePeriod( new DateTime($from), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($to));
```

I am then adding values of 0 to them. And after the query I am replacing 0s with values from DB if they exist.

This is my controller:

```
    public function timelines(Request $request){
    $from = $request['from'];
    $to = $request['to'];

    //if option time, get the date for number of views for each hour of the day
    if ($request['option'] == 'time'){
      $data = View::groupBy('time');
      $data->orderBy('time', 'ASC');

      if ($from !=0 && $to != 0)
         $data->whereBetween('views.created_at', [$from.' 00:00:00', $to.' 00:00:00']);

      $data->get([
           DB::raw('Hour(created_at) as time'),
           DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "count"')
           ]);

      foreach($data as $val){
       $dbData[$val->time] = $val->count;
      }

      $data = array_replace(array_fill_keys(range(0, 24), 0), $dbData);
    }

    //based on option selected, get data for number of articles read, number of comments, number of "bli med"
    else {

      $data = DB::table($request['option']);
      $data->select(DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as time'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'));

      if ($from !=0 && $to != 0) {
        //create an array with dates for the time interval specified
        $period = new DatePeriod( new DateTime($from), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($to));
        $dbData = [];

        //create an array with dates set as keys, and value 0
        foreach($period as $date){
            $range[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = 0;
        }
        $data->whereBetween('views.created_at', [$from.' 00:00:00', $to.' 00:00:00']);
      }

      $data->groupBy('time');
      $data->get();

      //create an array with dates set as keys, and value as count from DB
      foreach($data as $val){
        $dbData[$val->time] = $val->count;
      }

      //replace the values in two arrays
      $data = array_replace($range, $dbData);
    }

    return json_encode($data);
  }
```

When I have it like that I get:

> Trying to get property of non-object

for this piece of code:

```
foreach($data as $val){
    $dbData[$val->time] = $val->count;
}
```

Because I get builder returned back from the query.
How can I create a query where I can get all the results from the table, with the account of creating dates for the range of dates since beginning for that table.

Comment: Initialize `$dbData = [];` before that `foreach`

Comment: that is not the issue, I don't get any data from DB with this query, it returns builder, when I do dd($data); before the foreach loop

Comment: The error `Trying to get property of non-object` should have additional information about problematic object. Can u provide that additional info?

Comment: ErrorException in StatisticsController.php line 192:
Trying to get property of non-object                                                                   at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/home/vagrant/Projects/iCoop5.2/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Statistics/StatisticsController.php', '192', array('request' => object(Request), 'from' => '2016-05-01', 'to' => '2016-05-23', 'data' => object(Builder), 'val' => null, 'dbData' => array(), 'period' => object(DatePeriod), 'date'    ...

Comment: Have you tried to change that object builder to object using [Hydrate](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-can-i-get-object-with-query-builder-in-laravel?page=1)  ? Or try with 2 for each iterations foreach($val in $data) {foreach($abc in $val){
    $dbData[$abc->time] = $abc->count;
}}

Comment: But that is not the issue here, I need a date format that is gonna pull me all the rows from the DB